# Get checked unchecked value in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api

The code shows the required message on only one textbox but I want to show the required message on every checkbox.

It submits the form without checking the required validation, only the first checked textbox is showing validation and it didn't remove validation when I checked the box. It still shows the validation message.

Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance

```html
<div class="row" id="addform_allowances"></div>
```

```js
$('#add_button').click(function() {
  $('#hrm_employeeDesignation').html("");
  
  //designations dropdown 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'api/Hrm/hrm_payscales_api.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      action: 'designations'
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('#hrm_employeeDesignation').append($('<option disabled selected>Choose Option</option>'));
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $('#hrm_employeeDesignation').append($('<option>', {
          value: response[i].ID,
          text: response[i].NAME
        }));
      }
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      alert("Contact IT Department");
    }
  });
  
  //allowances dropdown
  $.ajax({
    url: 'api/Hrm/hrm_payscales_api.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      action: 'activeallowances'
    },
    success: function(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        console.log(response[i].ALLOWANCE);
        var append_allowances = "<div class='col-md-6 form-group'><input name='allowanceid[]' id='checkbox" + i + "'
        type = 'checkbox'
        value = '"+response[i].ID+"' > < label
        for = '' > & nbsp; & nbsp;
        "+response[i].ALLOWANCE+": < /label><input
        id = 'amountcheckbox"+i+"'
        type = 'number'
        name = 'allowance_amount[]'
        class = 'allowance_amount'
        disabled > < /div>";
        $('#addform_allowances').append(append_allowances);
      }
    },

    error: function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      alert("Contact IT Department");
    }
  });
});

$('#addform_allowances').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
  var checkboxidattr = $(this).attr("id");
  if ($('input[type=checkbox][id=' + checkboxidattr + ']').is(':checked')) {
    $('#amount' + checkboxidattr + '').attr('required', 'required');
    $('#amount' + checkboxidattr + '').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#amount' + checkboxidattr + '').removeAttr('required');
    $('#amount' + checkboxidattr + '').attr('disabled');
    $('#amount' + checkboxidattr + '').val('');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue you need to follw this below script.

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
      if(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('is checked');
      } else {
        alert('is not checked');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does your code add some validation to the form?